# need to re-enable onmouseon disabled with onclick event

Tags: javascript, prestashop

I'm trying to modify a prestashop module which allows to display groups of attributes by block: if the product has more than one group of attributes, the first block is displayed. After selecting one attribute of this group, the second group is displayed.

If the group of attributes is color, I need to display it in a popup.
I added this code at the end of the js file of the module:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$('.input-color').on('mouseover', function(e){

    let color = $(this).parent().find('.color').css('background-color');
    let image = $(this).parent().find('.color').css('background-image');
    console.log(color, 'this');
    if(color) {
        $('#cover-background').show().css({'background-color': color,'width': '400px', 'height': '400px',
            'margin': '0 auto', 'position': 'absolute', 'z-index': 99, 'left': '-60%', 'top': '40%'});
    }
    if(image) {
        $('#cover-background').show().css({'background-image': image,'width': '400px', 'height': '400px',
            'margin': '0 auto', 'position': 'fixed', 'z-index':999, 'left': '20%', 'top':'30%'});
    }
});

$('.input-color').on('mouseout', function(e){

    $('#cover-background').hide();
});
});
```

And a div with id=cover-background
The popup works fine for the first group of attributes.
But after clicking on one of attributes, the onmouseover is disabled.
You can see it here : http://decoelem2.kamilane.odns.fr/16-15976-table-basse-relevable-extensible-bessy.html (click on the button PERSONNALISER to display the first group)

The code to display the block (it's just a part of all the code of the module):

```
       $output += '<li class="float-xs-left pull-xs-left input-container color_' + k + ((/*(sizecolors && fa_colors[k]['value'] == '') ||*/ (fa_gray_color && in_array(k, attribNotInStockWith) && !allowBuyWhenOutOfStock)) ? ' fl_color_unavalable_li' : '') + '">\n\
                    <input id="color_' + k + '_' + j + '" class="input-color" type="radio"' + ((fa_gray_color && in_array(k, attribNotInStockWith) && !allowBuyWhenOutOfStock) ? ' disabled="true" title="' + not_avialable + '"' : ' title="' + attributes[l] + '"') + ' \n\
                    data-product-attribute="' + y + '" name="group[' + y + ']" \n\
                    value="' + k + '" onclick="set_selected_n(\'' + j + '\', ' + k + ',\'' + fa_key_val[j] + '\', 1);">\n\
                    <span ' + ((sizecolors && fa_colors[k]['value'] != '') ? 'class="color_select color" style="background-color: ' + fa_colors[k]['value'] + ';"' : '') + '\n\
                       ' + ((sizecolors && fa_colors[k]['value'] == '') ? 'class="color_select color texture" style="background-image: url('+fa_colors[k]['img']+')"' : '') + '\
                        title="' + attributes[l] + '">\n\
                        <span class="sr-only">' + attributes[l] + '</span>\n\
                        ' + ((fa_gray_color && in_array(k, attribNotInStockWith) && !allowBuyWhenOutOfStock) ? '<span title="' + not_avialable + '" class="disabled"></span>' : '') + '\n\
                    </span>\n\
                </li>';
        }
    }
```

I can send the file or all the module if you need it.

Thanks a lot for your help!

[edit] Here is all of the function (I think):

```
     function generate_html_content_bloc(first, id_group, id_group_next)

{

$output = '';

class_sup = '';

for (j in fa_groups) { //on parcourt les groupes d'attributs

    groupName_id = 'fa_group_' + j;

    groups = fa_groups[j];

    name_group = groups['name'];

    y = j.replace('g_', '');

    if (!first && id_group_next != j){

        if(array_key_exists(j, tread_group)){

            $(".product-variants").append(tread_group[j]);

        }

        continue;

    }

    $output += '<div id="field_' + j + '" class="clearfix product-variants-item">';

    $output += '<span class="control-label"><strong>Choisissez : </strong>' + name_group + ' </span><br />';

    attributes = groups['attributes']; //On a ici le tableau des attributs pour le groupe

    if (groups['group_type'] == 'radio') {

        $output += '<ul id="group_' + j + '" class="radio_btn_list radio_btn_list_' + j + '">';

        $output += '<li id="li_list_0_' + j + '" class="input-container pull-xs-left float-xs-left hide-element ' + class_sup + ' attr_disabled">\n\

          <input id="g_radio_0' + j + '" class="input-radio attribute_radio g_radio_' + j + '" type="radio" data-product-attribute="' + y + '" \n\

              name="group[' + y + ']" value="0"  checked="checked" title="' + not_avialable + '" disabled="true">\n\

          <span class="radio-label radio-label-desabled">&nbsp;</span>\n\

        </li>';

      for (var k in attributes) {

        l = k;

        k = k.replace('k_','');

        if (!fa_gray_radio && in_array(k, attribNotInStockWith) && !allowBuyWhenOutOfStock)

          continue;

        else if(!first && allowBuyWhenOutOfStock && displaydecoop && !in_array(k, attri_int_dec)) //on supprime les déclinaison non existantes

          continue;

        $output += '<li id="radio_' + k + '" class="input-container pull-xs-left float-xs-left' + ((fa_gray_radio && in_array(k, attribNotInStockWith) && !allowBuyWhenOutOfStock) ? ' attr_disabled"' : '') + '">\n\

          <input type="radio"' + ((fa_gray_radio && in_array(k, attribNotInStockWith) && !allowBuyWhenOutOfStock) ? ' disabled="true" title="' + not_avialable + '"' : '') + ' id="g_radio_' + j + '_' + k + '" \n\

            class="input-radio attribute_radio g_radio_' + j + '" data-product-attribute="' + y + '" name="group[' + y + ']" \n\

            value="' + k + '" onclick="set_selected_n(\'' + j + '\', ' + k + ',\'' + fa_key_val[j] + '\', 0);" />\n\

          <span class="radio-label">' + attributes[l] + '</span>\n\

        </li>';

      }

      $output += '</ul>';

    } else if (groups['group_type'] == 'color') {

        $output += '<ul id="group_' + j + '" class="clearfix">';

        $output += '<li id="li_list_0_' + j + '" class="float-xs-left pull-xs-left input-container color_' + j + ' selected hide-element ' + class_sup + '">\n\

            <input id="color_0_' + j + '" class="input-color" type="radio" data-product-attribute="' + j + '" name="group[' + y + ']" \n\

                value="0" checked="checked" disabled="true">\n\

            <span class="color_select color texture" style="background-image: url(' + fa_col_img_dir + 'croix.png)" title=""></span>\n\

        </li>';

        for (var k in attributes) {

          l = k;

          k = k.replace('k_','');

          if (!fa_gray_color && in_array(k, attribNotInStockWith) && !allowBuyWhenOutOfStock)

            continue;

          else if(!first && allowBuyWhenOutOfStock && displaydecoop && !in_array(k, attri_int_dec)) //on supprime les déclinaison non existantes

            continue;

            $output += '<li class="float-xs-left pull-xs-left input-container color_' + k + ((/*(sizecolors && fa_colors[k]['value'] == '') ||*/ (fa_gray_color && in_array(k, attribNotInStockWith) && !allowBuyWhenOutOfStock)) ? ' fl_color_unavalable_li' : '') + '">\n\

                    <input id="color_' + k + '_' + j + '" class="input-color" type="radio"' + ((fa_gray_color && in_array(k, attribNotInStockWith) && !allowBuyWhenOutOfStock) ? ' disabled="true" title="' + not_avialable + '"' : ' title="' + attributes[l] + '"') + ' \n\

                    data-product-attribute="' + y + '" name="group[' + y + ']" \n\

                    value="' + k + '" onclick="set_selected_n(\'' + j + '\', ' + k + ',\'' + fa_key_val[j] + '\', 1);">\n\

                    <span ' + ((sizecolors && fa_colors[k]['value'] != '') ? 'class="color_select color" style="background-color: ' + fa_colors[k]['value'] + ';"' : '') + '\n\

                       ' + ((sizecolors && fa_colors[k]['value'] == '') ? 'class="color_select color texture" style="background-image: url('+fa_colors[k]['img']+')"' : '') + '\

                        title="' + attributes[l] + '">\n\

                        <span class="sr-only">' + attributes[l] + '</span>\n\

                        ' + ((fa_gray_color && in_array(k, attribNotInStockWith) && !allowBuyWhenOutOfStock) ? '<span title="' + not_avialable + '" class="disabled"></span>' : '') + '\n\

                    </span>\n\

                </li>';

        }

    } else if (groups['group_type'] == 'select') {

        $output += '<select class="form-control form-control-select" name="group[' + y + ']"  data-product-attribute="' + y + '" id="group_' + j + '" \n\

            onchange="set_selected_n(\'' + j + '\', this.value,\'' + fa_key_val[j] + '\', 2);">';

        $output += '<option value="0" selected="selected" id="li_list_0_' + j + '">' + name_select + '</option>';

        for (var k in attributes) {

          l = k;

          k = k.replace('k_','');

          if (!fa_gray_select && in_array(k, attribNotInStockWith) && !allowBuyWhenOutOfStock)

            continue;

          else if(!first && allowBuyWhenOutOfStock && displaydecoop && !in_array(k, attri_int_dec)) //on supprime les déclinaison non existantes

            continue;

            $output += '<option value="' + k + '"' + ((fa_gray_select && in_array(k, attribNotInStockWith) && !allowBuyWhenOutOfStock) ? ' disabled="true" class="fa_disabled"' : '') + '>' + attributes[l] + '</option>';

        }

        $output += '</select>';

    }

    $output += '<span class="attribute-arrow-right arrow-'+groups['group_type']+' group_' + j + ' displaynone icon icon-arrow-right'+(((fa_attr_all && (id_group_next == j/* || first_first*/)) ? ' arrow-right-show' : ''))+'"><i class="material-icons">arrow_forward</i></span>';

  if(fa_attr_all && first_first)

    first_first = false;

  if(first || !fa_attr_all)

    $output += '</div>';

  if (first && !fa_attr_all) //si c'est lors du chargement et que c'est l'option bloc par bloc, on s'arrete à la premiere boucle

      return $output;

  if (!first && fa_attr_all){/*On affiche le résultat quand nous sommes en tout les blocs*/

    $('#field_' + id_group+' .attribute-arrow-right.group_'+ id_group).removeClass('arrow-right-show');

    $('#field_' + j).html($output);

    $output = '';

  }

}

if (first || !fa_attr_all)/*On retourne le résultat quand nous sommes en bloc par bloc*/

    return $output;

}
```

Comment: Where does `$output` come from? Where does it go afterwards?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The code is too long to be added. I can send you the file if you want. Here is the function :

Comment: Clarfiying your problem, tell me if this is correct: When hovering the initial group of colour properties, a pop-up appears (over top of the product images area). After making an initial colour selection, the pop-up never appears again, no matter what colour thumbnail you hover (initial group or otherwise).

Comment: Yes, it's correct. The popup works only with the initial colour properties but doens't work anymore after an initial colour selection. Thanks for your reply !

Comment: For information, the module allows to display all groups of attributes or group by group. I use only this second choice. Thus I need the popup only for this. Thanks a lot !